# how can send lavalink error to a discord error message for music bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, lavaplayer

hi im trying too get lavalink error and then convert error message to discord response error
i get console error with no problemo with this code, `.on("error", console.error)`

i tried to get it like this but i get undefined message as result,:

```
.on("error", () => {
if (this.textChannel) this.textChannel.send(util.embed().setColor(this.guild.me.displayHexColor).setDescription(`${error}`));
})
```

can anyone help me :(
im newbie,learning every day

[code looking on vs code for info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suRZB.png)

Comment: `.on("error", () => {` should be `.on("error", (error) => {`

Comment: get this now [object Object]

Comment: Yes, if you stringify an object, you'll receive that (`\`${error}\``)

Comment: how i stringify lavalink error message